# Speed of linq query grouping and intersect in particular

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Say 3 lists exist with over 500,000 records and we need to perform a set of operations (subsets shown below):

1) Check for repeating ids in list one and two and retrieve distinct ids while Summing up "ValuesA" for duplicate ids and put results in a list. Lets call this list list12.

2) compare all the values with matching ids between list 3 list12 and print results say to console.

3) ensure optimal performance.

This what i have so far:

```
var list1 = new List<abc>()
{ 
    new abc() { Id = 0, ValueA = 50},
    new abc() { Id = 1, ValueA = 40},
    new abc() { Id = 1, ValueA = 70}

};

var list2 = new List<abc>()
{ 
    new abc() { Id = 0, ValueA = 40},
    new abc() { Id = 1, ValueA = 60},
    new abc() { Id = 3, ValueA = 20},

};

var list3 = new List<abc>()
{ 
    new abc() { Id = 0, ValueA = 50},
    new abc() { Id = 1, ValueA = 40},
    new abc() { Id = 4, ValueA = 70},

};
```

1) with the help of the solution from here [link][1] I was able to resolve part 1.

```
var list12 = list2.GroupBy(i => i.Id)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                NewValueA = g.Sum(j => j.ValueA),
            });
```

2)I cant seem to properly get the complete result set from this part. I can get the matching account numbers, maybe someone knows of a **faster** way other than hashsets, but I also need the ValueA from each list along with the matching account numbers.

```
        foreach (var values in list3.ToHashSet().Select(i => i.ID).Intersect(list12.ToHashSet().Select(j => j.UniqueAccount)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(values)   //prints matching account number

            //?? how do I get ValueA with from both lists with this in the quickest way possible
        }
```

3) my only attempt at improving performance from reading online is to use hashsets as I seen in the attempt above but I may be doing this incorrectly and someone may have a better solution

Comment: Use a join. That gives you access to both sides.

Comment: @usr: thats the one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that any conversion to `HashSet`, however efficient, will increase performance. The reason is that the lists must be enumerated to create the `HashSet`s and then the `HashSet`s must be enumerated to get to the results.

If you put everything in one LINQ statement the number of enumerations will be minimized. And by calculating the sums at the end the number of calculations is reduced to the absolute minimum:

```
list1.Concat(list2)
     .Join(list3, x => x.Id, l3 => l3.Id, (l12,l3) => l12)
     .GroupBy (x => x.Id)
     .Select(g => new
             {
                 Id = g.Key,
                 NewValueA = g.Sum(j => j.ValueA),
             })
```

With your data this shows:

```
    Id  NewValueA
    0   90
    1   170
```

I don't know if I understood all requirements well, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: hi thanks for answering so quick and explaining but how are you getting 170 for Id1? Did you mean to type 140? I think you have the requirements down 100%. I'll check this and get back to you.

Comment: 40 + 70 + 60 (in list1 and list2).

Comment: youre right i forgot to add the second value in list1 :). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get access to both elements you probably want a join. A join is a very general construct that can be used to construct all other set operations.

Comment: While youre comment guided me in the right direction and is correct. I gave it to @Gert for showing me an how to go about it in detail and also ansering quicker. Thanks anyway.